# What does "expressions of opinion" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does "expressions of opinion" mean?

**Expressions of opinion** should be supported by reference to the authority on which they are made and the verifiable facts which support them.

Comment: If I say "wind is unpleasant" that is an "expression of opinion" – it is my opinion. The sentence requires that I back up that opinion with references as stated. The sentence is somewhat contradictory though, because if I cite an authority or verifiable facts, that is no longer an **opinion**.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I am not in complete agreement with you about its contradictoriness; I'd say its still an opinion. You might cite an authoritative anthropologist, who states that humans developed clothing because of the unpleasantness of wind, or various facts about unconscious reactions to wind. However "wind is unpleasant" remains an opinion because ,despite all that, I still find wind pleasant.

Comment: @sharur I agree, and it not about one's preferences. It may be my opinion that wind causes an elevation of mood and I must show studies or surveys that back up the opinion.

Comment: I don't think the cited usage is idiomatic. It reads to me like a "not-very-fluent" writer's attempt to "improve" on the standard phrasing: ***Opinions** should be supported by reference to...*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the "meaning" of a non-idiomatic usage (***expressions of opinion*** instead of just ***opinion***).

Answer (score 1):

An expression is the process of transmitting ideas, such as thoughts, concepts, or feelings, between entities (such as individuals or groups).

An opinion is a judgement or view; thus it is not a fact or truth.

An "Expression of Opinion" is used in your example to distinguish between an "Expression of Fact", which would not necessarily need the references that are required for an "Expression of Opinion".

Comment: I agree with your first two paragraphs. It is statements of facts that require support. Opinions are personal and subjective and thus are impossible to support. “i think this wind is unpleasant” may or may not reflect my true thoughts, but such opinions are almost never verified by a lie detector, which is the only conceivable method of validation.